# DNS on a Windows Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, dns, web, host

Good afternoon,

I'm moving the restnet.es domain to host on a Windows Azure Web Site, but it just doesn't work. I guess I made all the configuration correctly, changing the A and CNAME records on the domain register (arsys.es), but the Windows Azure portal doesn't catch it.

The DNS is seted as following: http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.restnet.es&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

As above, it seems is all working, pointing as expected to 137.117.224.218. But when I go into the Portal and set it up, I got this message:

"The DNS record for 'restnet.es' that points to 'restnetes.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you want to configure an A record, you must first create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for 'awverify.restnet.es' that points to 'awverify.restnetes.azurewebsites.net'. First allow the resource record to propagate, and then create the A record."

What am I doing wrong? Where is my mistake?

PS: this is the actual configuration:

```
awverify.restnet.es CNAME
awverify.restnetes.azurewebsites.net
restnet.es A
137.117.224.218
www.restnet.es CNAME
restnetes.azurewebsites.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Usage

*www.restnet.es* CNAME *restnetes.azurewebsites.net*

> it is in place, no action needed

## Verification

*awverify.www.restnet.es* CNAME *awverify.restnetes.azurewebsites.net*

> returns nothing, **you need to add record above into your DNS**

it will take max 48 hours to propagated.

Comment: awverify seems be a kind of "temporary key" of Windows Azure, it demands me to use when wanted to work with A records. I don't know why, and how change it on Azure until now...

Comment: it is for verification purposes.  unless you have that record in your DNS system won't activate the Usage record/link

Comment: I removed all records on the DNS server, and made only a new CNAME record, pointing to restnetes.azurewebsites.net, and now it's all working!